# assign the same label to multiple variables with the same suffix - R

Tags: r, dplyr, label

Is there a way to assign labels to multiple variables that, for example, end with a common suffix? I have a lot of variables that need to be labelled the same by common suffix. I was exploring doing this in `dplyr` and `labelled`, and am open to alternative ways. Something like this?--

```
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)   

df<-mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with("p")), 
                         funs(set_variable_labels(., labels ="these things end with p")))
```

**Edit:** seems to work with `sophisthse` function `set_variable_labels` but not `labelled` at least with this style of syntax. Adding `sophisthse` to the environment:

```
library(sophisthse)  
mtcars %>% select(ends_with("p")) %>% 
    sophisthse::set_variable_labels(., label = rep("these things end with p", length(.)))
```

**Edit:**
per below, I ended using `setattr` from `data.table`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Also, include the packages used.  Is this from `sophisthse`?  You may need `mutate_at(vars(ends_with("something")), funs(set_variable_labels(., labels = "these things are pretty much the same"))))`

Comment: Try `set_variable_labels(mtcars %>% select(ends_with("p")), labels =rep("these things end with p", 2))`

Comment: Or in a chain `mtcars %>% select(ends_with("p")) %>% set_variable_labels(., labels = rep("these things end with p", length(.))) %>% str`

Comment: These tips didn't work for me either but thank you. The error that some .data are not found occurred. Will keep testing...

Comment: I don't know what you meant by `not working`.  I couldn't find any errors with `mtcars` dataset and if you check the `str`, it shows the attributes

Comment: My misunderstanding. I didn't realize the `sophisthse` package was being called. It works using this package. Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with

```
library(dplyr)
library(sophisthse)
 mtcars %>% 
   select(ends_with("p")) %>% 
   set_variable_labels(., labels = rep("these things end with p", length(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work well too since using `setattr` from `data.table` will allow more types of attributes to be assigned besides labels if one is interested in storing notes or flags, for example, and can still be used with `dplyr` select helpers to apply a function across selected variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df<-mtcars%>% 
      mutate_at(vars(ends_with("p")),funs(setattr(.,"label","ends with p")))%>% 
      mutate_at(vars(ends_with("p")),funs(setattr(.,"description","aboutthisvariable")))%>% 
      mutate_at(vars(starts_with("c")),funs(setattr(.,"flag","watchoutforthattree")))
```